# What is the best toolset for developing an enterprise application for SMBs?

Tags: programming-languages, open-source, database-development, frameworks, erp

Need a Free, Fast(development and runtime) and Reliable(transactions and locking) tool set for creating an enterprise application for SMBs.

I'm thinking of an application framework + UI framework + DB which will help me in developing the software faster.

As it is known, business softwares need lot of similar UIs to be created. 
My idea is ...to create a new form with N number of fields and connecting it to the database for basic CRUD operations within 30min to 1hr.

I got the taste of Intersystems Cache technology stack with an app framework on top of it. To be frank...it is amazing... 
I'm looking out for something similar to this in opensource.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best toolset for living a
>   fullfilling life for suburban
>   professionals?
>
> Need a convenient, functional toolset
>   for living my life.  I'm thinking of a
>   moral code + religion + culture which
>   will help me life happier and better.

Ok I couldn't help myself.  You're asking for religion and any answer you get will be based more on personal preferences than one being actually "better" than another.

That being said, go with Ruby.  It's free, fully functional and comes with a lot of stuff, like Rails and an active community.  And, you get to look down on everyone else as a bonus.

My background is in Java and .NET, but if I had to start from scratch at this moment, I'd probably learn Ruby.